# Forgot to create partition before running pvmove

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, pvmove

I ran pvmove to migrate extents from an old LVM disk to a new one but I forgot to create the partition structure on the new disk first:

`pvmove /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc`

Everything seems to be fine, but I'm wondering if I should move it off the new disk again, create the partition structure, then back on?  It seems like the only caveat to not doing this is that someone else might look at the disk & realize there's no partition structure on it & format it.  I'm the only one who manages them at all at this point.

Also, is there a way to do this that doesn't involve more pvmoves?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the situation is documented, and you don't hire idiots who fdisk first and ask questions afterwards, I don't see there being any real risk of complications.  It's not that uncommon to use unpartitioned disks as components in volume groups and RAID sets, when there would only be one partition on the disk anyway.

Comment: +1 ms-dos disk label is obsolete. There is no reason, besides potential human error, to have LVM on top of it.